# Cannot set session variables inside HMVC module using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, hmvc, modular

I ran into a problem while using CI 3.0.3 with HMVC extension.
I want to set session variables when user successfully logs in. So I have User.php class which stores login view, and input validations.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == true):

    // prep auth, session
    $login_data = Array(
        'table'  => 'users',
        'cred'   => Array(
            'username' => $_POST['username'],
            'password' => $_POST['password'],
            'user_active' => 1
        )
    );

    $try = modules::load('auth/login', $login_data);
```

When validation runs, I'm sending data to Auth module, to login function. Login method runs SQL query to verify user inputs, if everything is right Login method sends user details to set_login_session method:

Auth/login:

```
$user_details_from_db = $this->lmodel->try_login($table, $login_data);

if($user_details_from_db) $this->set_login_session($user_details_from_db);
```

Auth/set_login_session

```
public function set_login_session($user_data) {

    $sess_data = Array(
        'id'        => $user_data->id},         // user id
        'username'  => $user_data->username},   // username
        'is_logged' => true
    );

    // set session data
    $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
}
```

I think this should set session variables but it's not working. When I dump all session data I see only:

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1454660014
)
```

BTW, when I move all set_login_session's content to main User.php controller and run same code there it works perfectly. But not in as HMVC module.

Also I load Session class via CI's autoload.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem, use HMVC in CI 3.0.3, Maybe HMVC Modular version extension is not compatible with CI 3.0.3 , session not work and query very slow. I downgraded to CI 3.0.1, its work perfectly.

I am using HMVC Modular from this :
https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads

Hope this help.

Comment: Tried it. Same, not working.
Probably I'm missing some silly mistake, but cannot find it.